# DocumentHelper requires xml decalration version to be lowercase

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm maintaining a old project, and after migrating to a new server environment,

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
```

But when I tried to parse an xml string:

```
Document dom = DocumentHelper.parseText(xml);
```

It prints error with:

> location error:Error on line 1 of document  : The version is required in the XML declaration. Nested exception: The version is required in the XML declaration.

The content of the xml is:

```
<?xml Version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Page>
<Common>
<Device Version="1.0.0" Type="H9" Customer="general " />
<Function Id="GetConfig" WatchId="355372020368356" Style="2"/>
</Common>
</Page>
```

And when I change the `<?xml Version` to lower case `<?xml version`, it gets through successfully.

But the source of xml is the thing I just cannot change, is there any way to configure the xml parser to accept the upper case one of xml declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It is the underlying XML parser that reports the problem. The easiest workaround is probably to "edit" the input file:

```
    Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(xml.replaceAll("^<\\?xml +Version", "<?xml version"));
```

Comment: Thank you, and I did do it as you told before you told that. But I'm wondering how that code can work in the previous environment.